# Changes to LP if a new constraint is added

Tags: linear-programming

[image]

Applying simplex, I found out the optimal solution to be $z^*=16$ and $x^{*} = (8,0,0,0,12)$ where $x_4,x_5$ are slack variables.

Now, suppose we add constraint $x_2+2x_3 = 3$

So, If I were to add this constraint to the optimal tableau, we see that this does ${\bf not}$ affect the values of $z_j-c_j$ and so optimality is not changed. This suggests that we have to consider $x_2+2x_3 \leq 3 $ and $x_2+2x_3 \geq 3$ which is same as $-x_2-2x_3 \leq -3$ and so after adding slack variables $x_6,x_7$,then we see that the feasibility is changed (primal feasibility). In this situation, do we run the dual simplex?

or the way to handle this situation is different than the way I thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(8,0,0)$ doesn't satisfy $x_2+2x_3=3.$ The value on the LHS is less than the $RHS$.

$$\max 2x_1+x_2-x_3-Mx_6$$
subject to 
$$x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_4=8$$

$$-x_1+x_2-2x_3 + x_5=4$$

$$x_2+2x_3+x_6=3$$

$$x \ge 0$$

At $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6)=(8,0,0,0,12,3)$, we have $x_1, x_5, x_6$ being basic variables and we can run primal simplex.

If the previous basis matrix is $B$, now, our basis matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ with its inverse being $\begin{bmatrix} B^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$ The main entries of the simplex tables are $$\begin{bmatrix}  B^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} A & 0\\ a_3^T & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} B^{-1}A & 0\\ a_3^T & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}  B^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} b \\ b_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} B^{-1}b  \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Why did you add slack to the new constraint if it was already an equiality?

Comment: so that we can move on from the current position in our simplex implementation.

Comment: Is it possible to add constraint to the optimal tableau of the “old” problem and take it from there? Maybe using dual simple?

Comment: Sure. I added a constraint and the variable $x_6$. With $x_1, x_5, x_6$ as the basis, most entries are identical with the old problem.

Comment: I have added an explanation why most entries are the same.

Comment: its very nice! I have another question, in the same LP, We know ${ \bf b} = (8,4)^T$, the RHS of the constraint. IF we were to to change the RHS of the constraints, as long as it is not negative, we are still feasible. But, if I were to change RHS of either first or second constraint, is there one that would change the optimal value of the function more?

Comment: I would look at the dual value.